# How to rewrite a piece of code without using string.Join and StringBuilder

Tags: c#, cefsharp

This is the whole code

```
string script = @"(function()
                        {
                            var linksArray = new Array();
                            for (var i = 0; i < document.links.length; i++)
                            {
                                linksArray[i] = [String(document.links[i].innerHTML),
                                        String(document.links[i].innerText),
                                        String(document.links[i].href)];
                            }
                            return linksArray;
                        })();";
var task = chrome.EvaluateScriptAsync(script);
task.ContinueWith(x =>
{
    var response = x.Result;
    if (response.Success && response.Result != null)
    {
        var list = (List<object>)response.Result;
        string s = "";
        foreach (List<object> item in list)
        {
            s = string.Join("\n", item.Select(item1 => $"{item1}"));
            textHtml.Text += s + Environment.NewLine;
        }
    }
}, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

How to rewrite a line of code below

```
s = string.Join("\n", item.Select(item1 => $"{item1}"));
```

by using simple foreach, if, for, etc. Without using `string.Join` and `StringBuilder`.

Comment: By "redo" you mean "rewrite"?  Are you not understanding what that line of code does, or, otherwise, what problem are you having in your attempt to implement this with basic loops?  Also, please be specific what the "etc." is that cannot be used.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: @Lance U. Matthews, yes i mean "rewrite", string.Join and StringBuilder these topics are new to me. That's why i want to rewrite these topics to topics what i know

Comment: i have no idea why you wanted to replace `string.Join` with `foreach` given `string.Join` is faster for concatenating strings. but you can iterate the `item` using `foreach(string tx in item)`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
s = string.Join("\n", item.Select(item1 => $"{item1}"));
```

equals

```
s = string.Empty;

for (int i = 0; i < item.Length; i++)
{
    var item1 = item[i];

    if (i > 0)
        s += "\n";

    s += $"{item1}";
}
```